# Can't trigger Xdebug break in PhpStorm using Laravel on Nginx

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, phpstorm, xdebug

I have been trying unsuccessfully to get Xdebug to work with Laravel running on php8.0-fpm on nginx.

I am using PhpStorm to trigger the breakpoints, but it seems that even `xdebug_break()` is not triggered.

These are all the configurations I have, and I can also post `phpinfo()` in a comment if needed:

nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dashboard.local;
    root /var/www/dashboard/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

php-config:

```
PHP 8.0.0 (cli) (built: Nov 27 2020 12:26:22) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.0-dev, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.0, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
➜  ~ php-config -v
Usage: /usr/bin/php-config [OPTION]
Options:
  --prefix            [/usr]
  --includes          [-I/usr/include/php/20200930 -I/usr/include/php/20200930/main -I/usr/include/php/20200930/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20200930/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext/date/lib ]
  --ldflags           [-L/usr/lib/php/20200930 ]
  --libs              [-lcrypt   -largon2 -lresolv -lcrypt -lutil -lrt -lm -ldl  -lxml2 -lssl -lcrypto -lpcre2-8 -lz -lsodium -largon2 -lcrypt ]
  --extension-dir     [/usr/lib/php/20200930]
  --include-dir       [/usr/include/php/20200930]
  --man-dir           [/usr/share/man]
  --php-binary        [/usr/bin/php8.0]
  --php-sapis         [cli fpm ]
  --phpapi            [20200930]
  --ini-path          [/etc/php/8.0/cli]
  --ini-dir           [/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d]
  --configure-options [--includedir=/usr/include --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --disable-silent-rules --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --libexecdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=/usr --enable-cli --disable-cgi --disable-phpdbg --with-config-file-path=/etc/php/8.0/cli --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --config-cache --cache-file=/build/php8.0-xu5Vr1/php8.0-8.0.0/config.cache --libdir=${prefix}/lib/php --libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/php --datadir=${prefix}/share/php/8.0 --program-suffix=8.0 --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --mandir=/usr/share/man --disable-all --disable-debug --disable-rpath --disable-static --with-pic --with-layout=GNU --without-pear --enable-filter --with-openssl --with-password-argon2=/usr --with-external-pcre --enable-hash --with-mhash=/usr --with-libxml --enable-session --with-sodium --with-system-tzdata --with-zlib=/usr --with-zlib-dir=/usr --enable-dtrace --enable-pcntl --with-libedit=shared,/usr build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu host_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/php8.0-xu5Vr1/php8.0-8.0.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -O2 -Wall -pedantic -fsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -g]
  --version           [8.0.0]
  --vernum            [80000]
```

xdebug.ini (/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini):

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so
; zend_extension = xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_host = http//dashboard.local
xdebug.remote_port = 9009
xdebug.remoce_connect_back = on
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.remote_log = "/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log"
xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
```

PhpStorm:

[image: PHPStorm config 8.0]

[image: Localhost Validation 8.0]

Thank you :)

Edit 1:

I've downgraded to php 7.4 and Xdebug 2.9.8, but it seems I still cannot get any response from Xdebug. As per what [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone) has asked for, here's all the configurations I have.

php config:

```
Usage: /usr/bin/php-config [OPTION]
Options:
  --prefix            [/usr]
  --includes          [-I/usr/include/php/20190902 -I/usr/include/php/20190902/main -I/usr/include/php/20190902/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20190902/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext/date/lib ]
  --ldflags           [-L/usr/lib/php/20190902 ]
  --libs              [-lcrypt   -largon2 -lresolv -lcrypt -lrt -lm -ldl  -lxml2 -lssl -lcrypto -lpcre2-8 -lz -lsodium -lcrypt -largon2 -lcrypt ]
  --extension-dir     [/usr/lib/php/20190902]
  --include-dir       [/usr/include/php/20190902]
  --man-dir           [/usr/share/man]
  --php-binary        [/usr/bin/php7.4]
  --php-sapis         [apache2handler cgi cli fpm ]
  --phpapi            [20190902]
  --ini-path          [/etc/php/7.4/cli]
  --ini-dir           [/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d]
  --configure-options [--includedir=/usr/include --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --disable-silent-rules --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --libexecdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=/usr --enable-cli --disable-cgi --disable-phpdbg --with-config-file-path=/etc/php/7.4/cli --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --config-cache --cache-file=/build/php7.4-efh2kh/php7.4-7.4.13/config.cache --libdir=${prefix}/lib/php --libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/php --datadir=${prefix}/share/php/7.4 --program-suffix=7.4 --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --mandir=/usr/share/man --disable-all --disable-debug --disable-rpath --disable-static --with-pic --with-layout=GNU --without-pear --enable-filter --with-openssl --with-password-argon2=/usr --with-external-pcre --enable-hash --with-mhash=/usr --with-libxml --enable-session --with-sodium --with-system-tzdata --with-zlib=/usr --with-zlib-dir=/usr --enable-dtrace --enable-pcntl --with-libedit=shared,/usr build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu host_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/php7.4-efh2kh/php7.4-7.4.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -O2 -Wall -pedantic -fsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -g]
  --version           [7.4.13]
  --vernum            [70413]
```

xdebug section from phpinfo():

[image: Xdebug 2.9.8 info]
[image: Xdebug 2.9.8 info part 2]

xdebug log:

empty

PHPStorm config:

[image: PHPStorm interpreter config php 7.4]
[image: Localhost Validation 7.4]

Comment: You are using XDEBUG 3 and the old parameters. Suggest you [check out the upgrade guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide) I spent all afternoon doing the same

Comment: You have Xdebug v3 .. but keep using Xdebug v2 config parameters. Please go through https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide and adjust your settings. Xdebug v3 uses DIFFERENT config params than Xdebug v2.

Comment: *"but it seems that even `xdebug_break()` is not triggered."* BTW -- this function now works a bit differently than in Xdebug v2 -- it no longer initiates a fresh debug session, it now only works as programmatic breakpoint and nothing more.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've tried using the parameters described in the upgrade guide, but I still can't make it work. If I won't figure it out I'll just downgrade to v2.

Comment: @VladMB Show what you have got now: 1) what config you are trying to use (php.ini), 2) what the actual/live config is (Xdebug section from `phpinfo()` output or `xdebug_info()` captured the same way as you are trying to debug. 3) What Xdebug log has to say about it 4) what PhpStorm config is. Xdebug 3 works just fine here, in both 2020.2.4 as well as 2020.3 RC

Comment: @LazyOne Also, to clarify, I am trying to trigger debug mode by calling a Laravel API route I have where I declare a random variable with a breakpoint on that line, and then phpinfo(). The breakpoint on the line before phpinfo never gets triggered. Also, I have enabled "Start listening for PHP Debug Connections". Yet I haven't seen it trigger in any way at all.

Comment: @VladMB 1) `xdebug.remote_host` is completely wrong. It has to be the host (or better the IP) where IDE is running. It's not your website domain name -- check the Xdebug docs what that is for. 2) If Xdebug log is empty .. then it may not even trying to debug (e.g. no "debug me" flag passed  (a cookie/get/post param etc)). Try adding `xdebug_break();` in your code -- any difference?

Comment: @LazyOne xdebug_break(); doesn't trigger at all...and I've tried setting the remote host before to localhost, 127.0.0.1, and my public and private ip, with no difference. Retested and it seems to be the same.

Comment: @VladMB Well ... try `xdebug.remote_autostart=1` then (so it will automatically try to debug every single request) -- that's for Xdebug 2 (v3 uses differently named parameter for that). Still look into the Xdebug log.

Comment: If still nothing .. then you must be doing something wrong. Hard to say what that might be .. could be something very basic .. but it's much easier to spot with own eyes that remotely via messages...

Comment: @LazyOne I think I will just try to purge everything and reinstall going by different tutorials until I get it. It's super frustrating that I can't get something seemingly so basic to work, when I had before, but I guess I just gotta keep trying. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: We can try a TeamViewer session if you wish .. but it has to be tomorrow (not today) and had to agree on time. I may spot something with my eyes that otherwise would miss/would not think about it. P.S. Can be now actually (but we would need to finish in 2.5 hrs max -- by 18:00 UK time, now it's 15:28)

Comment: @LazyOne Sorry, I just see your message now. I would really appreciate if you'd like to help me over TeamViewer. Just let me know when else it would be comfortable for you.

Comment: @VladMB Post you final solution as an answer (you can accept your own answers). This will help other users in a similar situation (answered question has better visibility + clearly solved problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a session with [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone) we figured that I was not using the proper mode for Xdebug, as I needed to set it to `debug`. Previously I had it set to `develop` which meant Development Aids, thinking it encompassed the Step Debugger as well.

This is how the final config ended up looking (for Xdebug 3.0.1):

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.client_port=9009
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
```

This then made it able for me to trigger breakpoints, provided I had the Xdebug Helper extension in chrome, or gave the XDEBUG_SESSION_START parameter (in my case = to PHPSTORM) when making a request.

Thank you again for the help, [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone)!